# RewriteRule works fine in a testing environment, but not on my website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am turning crazy with this .htaccess:

I made this (and testing it out here https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} my-website.com
RewriteRule ^SHORT(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1?devname=short [L,QSA]
```

The first rule rewrites `http://` into `https://`. That part works both in the testing website and on my own website.

The second should change `https://my-website.com/SHORT` into `https://my-website.com/?devname=short`. That part works fine in the testing website, but not at all on my own? I don't understand why?

Extra note: The website's root folder is bound to the `/www/` folder on the server, I don't know if it matters? (that's the OVH default)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't say "doesn't work", but be specific, as to what that actually means (no redirect, wrong redirect, an actual error message ...?)

Comment: This should be an internal rewrite to begin with, so there should be no need to check the host name first (unless you want to use the same .htaccess to handle multiple domains, pointing to the same folder?), and you should use a relative URL for the substitution, rather than a full, absolute one.

Comment: By doesn't work, here I mean it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I checked the host in case I want to use a multisite as you said, I have removed it since, since it's unnecessary at the moment. What does it change if all the sites point to the same folder or not? My .htaccess is at the root of the server, and my website is at /www/, a second would be at /www2/ for example.. Then checking for host would be relevant wouldn't it? This may be where my misunderstanding lies...

Answer (score 0):

Found where my problem was!

My .htaccess file was in the root folder of the server, it needed to be in the website's folder for the paths to be relative to there (so here, in `www`).

Which is why CBroe was confused about why I was checking the host (since here, it's indeed unnecessary).